# Ethernet keeps disappearing

Tags: networking, ethernet, realtek

Please, help me! Ubuntu is unusable, Ethernet keeps disappearing. I mean I have to keep restarting PC every 20 minutes - 1 hour to gain back an internet connection. I have integrated Realtek card (`Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)`), thought it was broken - bought a dedicated network card from tp-link (TG-3468), both, integrated and dedicated cards use same r8169 kernel module, and it seems there is something terribly wrong with it…

(same problem on Ubuntu 23.04 and 23.10)

```
driver: r8169
version: 6.5.7-x64v3-xanmod1
firmware-version: rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:06:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Found those logs by running :

```
Oct 17 19:01:35 eima NetworkManager[1409]: <info>  [1697558495.8368] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 17 19:01:35 eima NetworkManager[1409]: <info>  [1697558495.8371] device (enp6s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 17 19:01:35 eima NetworkManager[1409]: <info>  [1697558495.8377] device (enp6s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 17 19:01:35 eima NetworkManager[1409]: <info>  [1697558495.8379] dhcp4 (enp6s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 17 19:01:41 eima NetworkManager[1409]: <info>  [1697558501.8385] device (enp6s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 17 19:01:41 eima NetworkManager[1409]: <info>  [1697558501.8831] dhcp4 (enp6s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 17 19:01:41 eima NetworkManager[1409]: <info>  [1697558501.8831] dhcp4 (enp6s0): state changed no lease
Oct 17 19:01:41 eima NetworkManager[1409]: <info>  [1697558501.8837] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.

Comment: `sudo ethtool -s enp6s0 speed 100 duplex full`

this command seem to help a bit, why is that?

Comment: AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. If you have new information on your original question, [edit] the question and add it. If you have a new question, [ask] it. Do not try to start conversations in a Comment. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: The fact that speed seems to matter may point to a wonky cable. Can you try a different cable?

Answer (score 0):

As weird as this sounds, the issue has been solved by updating ASrock motherboard BIOS to the latest `AGESA Combo V2 PI 1.2.0.B`. The system has been rock solid for the past couple of days now. It appears NOT to be Ubuntu or hardware issue at all.